# getElementsByClassName() not finding an element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am writing a Chrome extension and am trying to get  elements of the class col-xs-6 col-sm-3 using getElementsByClassName(). 
[webpage source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMtZU.png)

In my content script I have the lines

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-6 col-sm-3");
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
  console.log(cells[i]);
  // other code
}
```

When I ran the script however, nothing was displayed on the console.

I tried the following to hopefully find some answers

```
var cells = document.getElementsbyId("div");
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
  console.log(cells[i].className);
}
```

The console displayed a list of class names, however, the ones I were searching for were not among them.

How should I go about trying to access these elements?

EDIT: since the div tag I was searching for was inside an iframe, I did the following to try and access it.

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var cells = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-6 col-sm-3");
```

However, on the page's console, I got the message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined'

I printed the length of the collection of elements with the iframe tag to the console and got 0.

How can I access the iframe?

Comment: Have you tried to wait for the content to load before the code executes? `$(document).ready()?` or `DOMContentLoaded()`?